# Windows server 2008r2 crashed overnight - dump log

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, server-crashes, bsod

My windows server crashed overnight last night with a BSOD. I managed to get a log of the dump file which is here, it appears as if google chrome was the culprit, was wondering if anyone with more knowledge than me could dig out any more from this dump:

http://www.sendspace.com/file/99vdwn

Comment: I'm voting to close on this one because it's not a real question (and, possibly, not constructive). If this were edited to talk about the crash dump analysis process I could see it being useful. Otherwise I think it's just a posting asking somebody to perform crash dump analysis pro bono.

Comment: Chrome On a server??

Comment: well the site is called ServerFault...i have a fault on my server...i don't see the problem?

Comment: @PaulHinett: The intent of the site is to build a useful knowledge base for the sysadmin community. Your question and the response may well be helpful to you, but doesn't build anything for the community to use as reference. To my mind, the fact that the Server Fault site provides technical support is just a secondary artifact of the site's real mission. Your question and the answer amount to a technical support task and not a piece of knowledge that can be used by the community for future reference. That's my problem with it.

Comment: I agree with @EvanAnderson on this. "Here's a crash dump, someone analyze it for me" is not what this site is here for. [ask] will outline some requirements for asking a "good" question that include listing what you've already tried, where you're stuck, etc. Just saying "I have a problem, someone fix it" is insulting and implies that our time is less valuable than yours since you can't be bothered to even dig into your own problem yourself.

Comment: I do understand what your saying, but I don't have that kind of low level knowledge to understand a dump file which is why i asked for help. I do research everything i possibly can but sometimes i need a little push...like today, this question eventually helped me fix my problem.

Comment: I'm looking for answers to problems with my server and this question/answer helped. Those who voted to close the question didn't help. Too many sticklers for the rules on this site. Thanks to those who answered the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MODULE_NAME: pci

IMAGE_NAME:  pci.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4a5bc117

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x122_pci!ExpressRootPortAerInterruptRoutine+27f

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x122_pci!ExpressRootPortAerInterruptRoutine+27f
```

This looks like a graphics card / chip hardware failure.

Comment: Or a driver issue, a power fluctuation or a memory error that just hits that damn thing.

Comment: so basically, very difficult to find the route cause unless it's reproducible.

Comment: Yeah just replace PCIe card, this is pretty much simple. This could be another card to with dodgy driver.

Comment: I would simply wait to see if the error returns.  It could be the card or it could be the driver.  My bet would be the driver.

Comment: Thank you, this lead me into the right direction...in the end it was down to my power settings being set to 'Balanced' instead of 'High performance'. In effect this turned the PCI-Express link state power management from 'Moderate power savings' to 'no power savings'. I had thousands of errors in my error log before, now i have none.